# how can i suppress unchecked cast warnings before destructuring declaration?

Tags: kotlin

the IDE show me the tips that @Suppress can not placed before destructuring declaration

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
var test = authentication.details as Pair<String?,String?>
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val (token,role) = authentication.details as Pair<String?,String?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the expression like this:

```
val (token,role) = @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (authentication.details as Pair<String?,String?>)
```